# Android Back Timer Button

Tags: android, text, timer

i want to make a simple timer of 60 sec. When i tap the button my timer begins. And when the time=0 then set text to some string. Help me how can i do it for android inside Activity:

```
package com.example.gameprocess;


public class GameProcess extends Activity {

private static int rez = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gameprocess);


 final TextView Textkolvo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.kolvo);
 final TextView Texttime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texttime);
 final Button Butklik = (Button)findViewById(R.id.klik);
```

And when i tap this button my time have to begin...

```
 Butklik.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Textkolvo.setText(String.valueOf(rez));
    }
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a member variable for the seconds

```
int secondsLeft = 0;
```

and put this in `onCreate`:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable updateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        secondsLeft--;
        textTime.setText(String.valueOf(secondsLeft));
        if (secondsLeft == 0) {
            textKolvo.setText("Game over.");
        } else {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
};

butKlik.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (secondsLeft == 0) {
            secondsLeft = 60;
            textTime.setText(String.valueOf(secondsLeft));
            handler.postDelayed(updateTimeTask, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do make a TimerReceiver which extends BroadCastRecevier and able to receive these intents receive:

Define it in  **Manifest**  file to receiving the following **Intents**:

```
<receiver android:name=".TimerReceiver" exported="false" >

    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.yourpackagename.starttimer"/>
        <action android:name="com.yourpackagename.endtimer"/>
        <action android:name="com.yourpackagename.restarttimer"/>
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

What you need to write a BroadcastReceiver in your application

```
public class TimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String START_TIMER  =  "com.tcs.starttimer";
public static final String END_SESSION  =  "com.tcs.endsession";
public static final String RESTART_SESSION="com.tcs.restartsession";

private int sessionTimer=10*60*1000; //your time of counter in miliseconds
private int tickTime=1000; //tick time to decrease the counter in one milisecond


@Override
public void onReceive(Context contextdata, Intent intent) {

String actionString=intent.getAction();

    if(actionString.equals(TimerReceiver .START_TIMER)){

     timerStart();
}
    } else if(actionString.equals(TimerReceiver .END_SESSION)){

     //write what you want on ending the session

    }

 }


  void timerStart(){

     try{
         cTimer.cancel();
     }catch(Exception e){

     }

     cTimer=new CountDownTimer(sessionTimer,tickTime) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    counter++;

    }

      @Override
      public void onFinish() {
        //Log.d("counter","finish.counter: "+counter);
        int timeout=(sessionTimer/1000)-(tickTime/1000);
        if(counter==timeout){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Session Timeout",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(END_SESSION));
        }

      }
       }.start();
    }

 }
```

you can add one more action like to restart the timer if you need.

What your Activity need to do on tap on the button:

```
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent((TimerReceiver .START_TIMER));
```

In my case i am increasing the cound you can do it in reverse too. Enjoy working for me hope it will help you.